# Get typeof DataGrid data and cast as it

Tags: wpf, gridview, casting, datatable, itemssource

I'm having a problem with getting data of gridview and convering it into `DataTable`. Acually its like some of datagrids in my application have `ItemsSource` which I can cast as `DataView`, but another got `ItemsSource` defined in application.

For example:

DataGrid1 - ItemsSource = DataView (straight from database)
DataGrid2 - ItemsSource = ObservableCollection of Product
DataGrid3 - ItemsSource = ObservaleCollection of Categories

Error I'm getting:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   `` System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[myApp.Product] ``
>   to type `System.Data.DataView`.

I want to reach something like this:

```
  DataTable dt = null;
  try
  {
       dt = ((DataView)dg.ItemsSource).ToTable();
  }
  catch
  {
       Type t = dg.ItemsSource.GetType();
       dt = ((t)dg.ItemsSource).ToTable();
  }
```

So actually I'd like to get collection as object and cast `ItemsSource` as `DataTable`.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible... your error said

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[myApp.Product]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'

This means that there is no direct casting relationship between these classes. In order to provide that, you'd have to extend the `ObservableCollection<T>` class and override the `explicit` cast operator:

```
public class MyObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<YourDataType>
{
    public static explicit operator DataView(MyObservableCollection collection)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (YourDataType item in collection)
        {
            // fill your DataTable however you want to here
        }
        return new DataView(table);
    }
 }
```

You can find out more from the [explicit (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28VS.80%29.aspx) page at MSDN. You can find out how to fill a `DataTable` from the [DataView.Table Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.table.aspx) page at MSDN.

UPDATE >>>

This is *not* a method. It is a cast operator. It is used for casting one type into another. Like `(int)` in the following example:

```
int intValue = (int)doubleValue;
```

You asked how to cast an `ObservableCollection` into a `DataView`. My answer shows you how to do exactly that:

```
DataView dataView = (DataView)yourCustomObservableCollection;
```

Or from *YOUR* example:

```
dt = ((DataView)dg.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

... assuming that there is an instance of this custom `MyObservableCollection` set as the `dg.ItemsSource`.

You said

> DataGrid2 - ItemsSource = ObservableCollection of Product DataGrid3 - ItemsSource = ObservaleCollection of Categories

1. So first, create a new class like I showed you... call it whatever you like.
2. Next, replace your current `ObservableCollection` instances with your new `MyObservableCollection` instances.

That's it. I don't know how to explain it any more than that. If you *really* don't understand this, then you have no place asking these questions. I suggest that you go to MSDN to learn all about casting and then come back to make sense of this.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but actually it is first time I see something like explicit operator. If it possible, could You please share some sample code how should I use it? For type Product for example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I changed the first link in my answer (explicit (C# Reference)) to a page that explains its use and provides examples in C#. Please see that page for more help.

Comment: Hmm, in example you show there is

 Fahrenheit f = new Fahrenheit(100.0f);

which run public static explicit operator Celsius(Fahrenheit f) with parameter. So my maybe stupid question is that what should I pass to get return object as datatable?

Comment: Why do you want to return a `DataTable`? Your code (`dt = ((DataView)dg.ItemsSource).ToTable();`) is expecting a `DataView`. If you *really* want to do that, just change the `DataView` in the `explicit` operator definition that I gave you to `DataTable` and return a `DataTable` instead of a `DataView`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be DataView instead of DataTable. My question should be more like how to pass collection into explicit and get returned data?

Comment: Dude... read the linked page. This will enable you to cast your custom `ObservableCollection` class into a `DataView` instance using your *existing* code: `dt = ((DataView)dg.ItemsSource).ToTable();`. This does *exactly* what you asked for.

Comment: Still not sure if I dont understand that or you dont understand my question. So I put code you show in post, fill table and my code is now like DataTable dt = null; 
                dt = ((DataView)dg.ItemsSource).ToTable();
I dont have question how does it work because now I know that. Im just wonder how to raise that method and convert my itemssource..